# General query on before saveas event in excel

Tags: excel, vba

My query is this, does the excel before saveas event macro need to be stored in "this workbook" or can it be stored as a separate module to enable it to run on any open workbook?

Answer (score 1):

It can be stored anywhere, so long as you reference the alternate workbook correctly.

For example this code snipped can be saved in "this workbook", but will save another open file.

```
Set wbTHATWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
wbTHATWorkbook.SaveAs (strPath & strName), FileFormat:=51
```

For this example, you must declare your wb variable first.